# Creación de Grupos por rendimiento en Python

Tags: python

Hola estoy realizando este código en el cual se pasa una lista T que contiene el rendimiento de cada trabajador y un K que es el máximo de trabajadores por grupo.
El trabajador con mejor rendimiento del grupo mejorara el rendimiento de los demás trabajadores del grupo.

Para el ejemplo si se pasa T=[1,15,7,9,2,5,10] y K=3 El arreglo que maximiza el rendimiento seria:

- [[1,15,7] , [9] , [2,5,10]] cuando el rendimiento del mejor se pasa a los demás quedaría [[15,15,15] , [9] , [10,10,10]] por lo que al sumar 15+15+15+9+10+10+10 da como resultado 84.
  Por lo que me retornara como salida una lista en pares de los índices que representa desde que integrante hasta que integrante comienza y finaliza cada uno de los grupos conformados de la siguiente manera [[1, 3], [4, 4], [5, 7]].

ya que si los grupos se distribuyen de otra forma como:

- [[1] , [15,7,9] , [2,5,10]] ya que al sumar [[1] , [15,15,15] , [10,10,10]] da como resultado 76
- [[1,15,7] , [9,2,5] , [10]] ya que al sumar [[15,15,15] , [9,9,9] , [10]] da como resultado 82

Por lo que No es posible superar el rendimiento del primer arreglo del primer ejemplo

Por lo tanto intente el siguiente código en python el cual me tiene que dar como respuesta [[1, 3], [4, 4], [5, 7]] pero en cambio recibo la siguiente [[1, 3], [4, 6], [7, 9]] y no se como corregirlo, agradecería alguna idea para corregirlo. Muchas Gracias.

```
def mejor_trabajador(trabajadores):
    # Devuelve el índice del mejor trabajador
    mejor = max(trabajadores)
    return trabajadores.index(mejor)

def formar_grupos(T, K):
    grupos = []
    # Iteramos sobre el arreglo T en grupos de K trabajadores
    for i in range(0, len(T), K):
        grupo = T[i:i+K]
        # Determinamos el mejor trabajador del grupo
        mejor = mejor_trabajador(grupo)
        # Actualizamos el valor de cada trabajador en el grupo para que sea igual al del mejor
        for j in range(len(grupo)):
            grupo[j] = grupo[mejor]
        # Guardamos el rango de índices del grupo en la lista de resultados
        grupos.append([i+1, i+K])
    return grupos

# Ejemplo de uso
T = [1, 15, 7, 9, 2, 5, 10]
K = 3
N = len(T)
resultado = formar_grupos(T, K)
print(resultado)  # Imprime [[1, 3], [4, 4], [5, 7]]
```

Comment: ¿Los grupos tienen que ser de elementos seguidos? O sea, qué pasaría si el arreglo es `[1,2,3,4,5,14,15]`, ¿se puede formar grupos tipo: `[[1,2,14], [3,4,15], [5]]`?

Comment: Hola, Si los elementos deben tomarse de forma consecutiva.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No pude evitar buscar mi propia solución al problema.

La idea es ir tomando elemento por elemento y ver donde se produce el mayor valor: si lo coloco junto con los anteriores o junto con los siguientes.

```
def formar_grupos(T, K):
    lista = [[T.pop(0)]] # Contendra sublistas de T
    try:
        while T:
            top = lista[-1]
            #   Calcular el valor según ponemos el elemento
            #   en la sublista actual o en la siguiente
            valor_act = max(*top, *T[0:(K-len(top))])
            valor_fut = max(T[:K])

            if valor_act < valor_fut or len(lista[-1]) == K:
                #   Si el elemento rinde más en la próxima sublista,
                #   o si está ya está llena, colocarlo en una
                #   nueva sublista.
                lista.append([T.pop(0)])
            else:
                #   Agregarlo a la sublista actual.
                lista[-1].append(T.pop(0))

    except IndexError:
        pass

    #   Generar la lista de indices (principio, final)
    indice = 1
    index = []
    for sublista in lista:
        ultimo = indice + len(sublista)
        index.append((indice, ultimo - 1))
        indice = ultimo

    return lista, index
```

La función retorna la lista con sublistas de valores y la lista con tuplas que te dan los indices.

#### Demo

```
T = [1, 15, 7, 9, 2, 5, 10]
K = 3
lista, index = formar_grupos(T, K)
print(lista)
print(index)
```

produce:

```
[[1, 15, 7], [9], [2, 5, 10]]
[(1, 3), (4, 4), (5, 7)]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, tu aporte me fue de mucha ayuda, funciona a la perfección :D.